# While loop and if statements

Tags: python, if-statement, while-loop

I have a string and  k = number, which is the length of a substring that has the same letter repeated in a row. How can I have the wanted output only?
The expected output: For length  3, found the substring ddd!

```
my_string = 'aabadddefggg'
k = 3
x = 1
c = 1
while x < len(my_string):
    if my_string\[x\] == my_string\[x-1\]:
        c += 1
    else:
        c = 1
    if c == k:
        print("For length  " + str(k) + ", found the substring " + my_string\[x\] \* k + "!")
        break
    else:
        print("Didn't find a substring of length " + str(k))
        break
    x += 1
The output: 
Didn't find a substring of length 3
Didn't find a substring of length 3
Didn't find a substring of length 3
Didn't find a substring of length 3
Didn't find a substring of length 3
For length  3, found the substring ddd!
```

Answer (score 0):

get rid of the break after didnt find the string. Your code means that once you evaluate `c == k` you will always break beacuse you have the `break` in both the `if` and the `else` meaning you can never reach `x += 1`

```py
my_string = 'aabadddefggg'
k = 3
x = 1
c = 1
while x < len(my_string):
    if my_string[x] == my_string[x-1]:
        c += 1
    else:
        c = 1
    if c == k:
        print("For length  " + str(k) + ", found the substring " + my_string[x] * k + "!")
        break
    else:
        print("Didn't find a substring of length " + str(k))
    x += 1
```

**OUTPUT**

```
Didn't find a substring of length 3
Didn't find a substring of length 3
Didn't find a substring of length 3
Didn't find a substring of length 3
Didn't find a substring of length 3
For length  3, found the substring ddd!
```

Answer (score 0):

Even better, put your else statement under the while, this way:

```
my_string = 'aabadddefggg'
k = 3
x = 1
c = 1
while x < len(my_string):
    if my_string[x] == my_string[x-1]:
        c += 1
    else:
        c = 1
    if c == k:
        print("For length  " + str(k) + ", found the substring " + my_string[x] * k + "!")
        break
    x += 1
else:
    print("Didn't find a substring of length " + str(k))

# For length  3, found the substring ddd!
```

With k = 4 (the else statement is executed if the end of the loop is reached, which happens only if it doesn't break out of it):

```
# Didn't find a substring of length 4
```